# static method or non-static method using static field

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `static const std::vector<SomeType>` field in my class. I have two `private` methods that uses this field (searching methods). 
They do not use another members of my class. Should they be define as `static` or normal methods?

What should I prefer? What are advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 3):

Methods that reference only static members should generally be defined static. This lets you access these methods without creating an instance of a class, and also access them from static context (e.g. from a non-member function).

The only exception to this rule is when you need to make this access from a member function defined virtual. In this case you have no option to make your function static, because static functions cannot override virtual functions.

Comment: The part starting 'because' is a *non sequitur*. Whether static methods can be overridden has nothing to do with whether you can call them from virtual methods.

Comment: @EJP I didn't say that static member functions cannot be overridden, all I am saying is that static member functions cannot override virtual functions from the base class. In other words, if you are writing a function as an override for a base class virtual function, you need to make it non-static even if it accesses only static members.